# ARC Welder can't work my google chrome

Tags: google-chrome-arc

ARC runtime version: I don't know but I downloaded it on this site, https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/arc-welder/emfinbmielocnlhgmfkkmkngdoccbadn.
App version:The above is a correct statement

Chrome:46.0.2490.71 m
Platform:Windows 10

Hi there
I have used ARC Welder app about two months, but this words showed up since yesterday when I start every apk file, "You are using ARC Welder on a non-Chrome OS device. Platform specific bugs exist.", even though I turned on this app using Chrome.
Why did it happened to me? Can you tell me how to fix this problem?
Reinstalling the ARC Welder can't fix it.

Comment: Well I cant answer your question but it certainly made me smile.

Answer (score 0):

Now ARC is no longer supported on 32-bit x86 platforms and those platforms will no longer receive updates after October 13, 2015.
https://developer.chrome.com/apps/getstarted_arc

So you have to install 64bit version of chrome. or reinstall chrome.
Don't need to uninstall, just install 64bit it will upgrade your chrome,
you may need to reinstall ARC.

It worked for me, warning is still showing but working.

Answer (score 0):

makes sure that you also disable your antivirus and firewall!

If the issue persists you can check also your WEBGL acceleration on **chrome://flags and chrome://gpu** and enable it then relaunch it again

Also check on the rendering list override and relaunch the browser and try again.